# About the part in cruces of Sappho Lobel-Page 46

Tags: greek, poetry, sappho

The part of fragment in the title reads:

> κἂν μέν τε τύλαγκας ἀσπόλεα

Now, the only easy amendation that comes to mind here (other than erasing the space after τε) is κἂν->κὰμ. That gives us three intelligible words: κὰμ=κατὰ, down, μέν, probably to be matched by δέ further in the poem, and τε, which the author says is not a conjunction (οὐ γὰρ ὁ τέ σύνδεσμος), so it must be =σε, "you" (accusative). But it leaves two words I cannot make sense of: τύλαγκας and ἀσπόλεα. Now, [Edmonds](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/figuring-out-the-grammar-of-edmonds-57-edmonds-version-of-the-part-in-cruces-o) has gone very creative with this, heavily amending it. Wilamowitz has thought of αἴ κε κάμηι τέα, to join it with the rest of LP 46, and that is also very heavy. Bergk has κὰμ μὲν τὲ τύλαν κασπολέω, removing two letters and correcting one. Lobel-Page says "alii alia" after metioning Wilamowitz's conjecture. I was wondering:

1. What other proposals have been made?
2. Is there any way to make sense of those two words as they are, or what is the least amendation required to make sense of them? Would reading τετύλαγκας help?